# python timeit: function with decorator

Tags: python, caching

I am trying to figure out whether to compile regex expressions upfront, or alternativelt for startup speed, only compile they once when they are first required.

I can use timeit to test:

```py
re.compile(r'#(?:(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|(?:[\da-f]{4}){1,2})|rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)')
```

I don't know know how to figure out how long the parser takes (or how to use timeit to time it) to see the following code (not execute it, just "see" it).

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def get_color_pattern():
    return re.compile(r'#(?:(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|(?:[\da-f]{4}){1,2})|rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python code is interpreted "top to bottom". Therefore, if you declare variables either side of your function that are initialised with a "timestamp" you can deduce that the difference between those values will be the time taken to parse the code between them. So, for example,

```
from functools import cache
import time
import re

start = time.perf_counter()
@cache
def get_color_pattern():
    return re.compile(r'#(?:(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|(?:[\da-f]{4}){1,2})|rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)')
print(time.perf_counter()-start)

start = time.perf_counter()
re.compile(r'#(?:(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|(?:[\da-f]{4}){1,2})|rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)')
print(time.perf_counter()-start)
```

**Output:**

```
5.995000265102135e-06
0.00024428899996564724
```

Thus we see the difference in time taken to parse the function versus compiling the expression

Comment: I think its a good approach to time both the same way as you did. Thanks I did not know about perf_counter! Wow such a big difference! Will definately be going with the cached function calls.

Comment: Parsing the function is done before the whole program is even started.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check how long it takes with the cache generated, just run the function once before timing to generate the cache.

```
from functools import cache
import re
import timeit

@cache
def get_color_pattern():
    return re.compile(r'#(?:(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|(?:[\da-f]{4}){1,2})|rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)')

# Run once to generate cache
get_color_pattern()
number = 1000

t = timeit.timeit(get_color_pattern, number=number)

print(f"Total {t} seconds for {number} iterations, {t / number} at average")
```

Out: `Total 4.5900000000001495e-05 seconds for 1000 iterations, 4.5900000000001496e-08 at average`

Running with `cache` commented out, seems to be roughly 10x slower:
`Total 0.0004936999999999997 seconds for 1000 iterations, 4.936999999999997e-07 at average`

As pointed out by Kelly Bundy, `re.compile` already includes a [built in caching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) feature.

Comment: @KellyBundy The later of the comments is the result from a run without caching, i.e. 4.937e-7 seconds per call on average, otherwise the the script was exactly the same.

Comment: Seeing the [effect of the regex cache](https://tio.run/##ZY7BioNADIbv8xTBPXSmuC7WdlkE2QdZi1jN2AGdGbLxsFif3Q6rh9KGwJf8Icnv//jqbPblaVnM4B0xEIqtYjOgYSFa1NAhV43rHVW@ZkayUuUCQhDySDYgadzgTY@Sdm/yOw/5U7b1uz5P2aymND7MtwftuGnqRt2llGUbumyOn1iqnRLCjsMFCQpIhdCOoAITHta2Q3naXHCYrnaTFfLFcAzrnWKF@t/zZCxLHU0MH9sc9pDiJ@SnJNUzjL@RWpY7) (not `@cache`) is also interesting.

Comment: So I wouldn't call it "without caching".

Comment: @KellyBundy Interesting, Im not very familiar with `re`, so I didn't know about the builtin caching feature. So I guess when using `@cache` you access the cached values a bit earlier, so you save a bit more time, but regex caching itself provides a very substantial time saving on its own.